# How to search element in array (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c

I am new to Objective-C and I was looking for some help with my code. I want to search a word in a array.

```
@[@{
"name":"nick",
"Id":"2"
},
@{
"name":"Anna",
"Id":"4"
}]
```

I want to search name "nick" in array and fetch that complete object and create new array. I don't know how to do this in Objective-C.

Comment: Please be more precise. Is this about JSON arrays (that's what it looks like), or about filtering an `NSArray` of your custom `NSObject` subclasses (that's not what it looks like at all)? Also, show your attempts so far. SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: I would interpret the question as not knowing how to access a dictionary (NSDictionary) in an array (NSArray) and create a new array. Yeah, there's not a lot of detail there, but there's enough to get the gist of Renee's question. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSArray * names = @[@{"name":"nick","Id":"2"},@{"name":"Anna","Id":"4"}];
NSMutableArray * results = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];
for ( NSDictionary * name in names )
    {
    if ( [name[@"name"] isEqualToString:@"nick"] )
        {
        [results addObject:name];
        }
    }
```

Something like that. Written from memory and not tested.